# Add custom classes to node links

Tags: nodes, 8, theming

How can I add custom classes to node links in Drupal 8?

I want to add some classes to the *Read more* and *Add new comment* links in article teasers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your theme open file THEMENAME.theme, example in my case THEMENAME is bartik and file is bartik.theme add code below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_links().
 */
function bartik_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['links']['node-readmore'])) {
    $variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'css-readmore';
  }

  if (isset($variables['links']['comment-add'])) {
    $variables['links']['comment-add']['link']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'css-comment';
  }

}
```

**Update:**

Code above will add css class to any readmore link, to add for article only you can add preprocess and check type is article.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node.html.twig.
 */
function bartik_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  ...

  if ($variables['teaser'] && $variables['node']->getType() == 'article') {
    $node_type_is_article = &drupal_static('node_type_is_article');
    $node_type_is_article = TRUE;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_links().
 */
function bartik_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
  if ($node_type_is_article = &drupal_static('node_type_is_article')) {
    if (isset($variables['links']['node-readmore'])) {
      $variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'css-readmore';
    }

    if (isset($variables['links']['comment-add'])) {
      $variables['links']['comment-add']['link']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'css-comment';
    }
  }
}
```

Clear all cache and see result. Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: OP referred only to article teasers. This will ad it to all content.

Comment: Hi J. Reynolds, i just update code to add css for node type article only, please check is it ok.

Comment: Bravo, grateful.

Comment: Would this not cause issues for when there are multiple nodes being displayed on a page? You're setting a boolean value into the statics, but that'll apply for every node that gets preprocessed.