# Rename "Read More"

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

I wanted to rename "Read more" in teaser (node--blog--teaser.html.twig) to something like "Continue" or anything else.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your theme open file THEMENAME.theme, example in my case THEMENAME is bartik and file is bartik.theme add code below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_links().
 */
function bartik_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
    if (isset($variables['links']['node-readmore'])) {
      $variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#title'] = t('Read more custom text');
    }
}
```

Clear all cache and see result.

About add custom class to readmore link you can check here: [Add custom classes to node links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194861/add-custom-classes-to-node-links/194881#194881)

Comment: Only issue is that you don't have access to the node that the links are for, meaning that you can't change it conditionally based on the node type.

Comment: Another issue would be that Bartik is a core theme. And it actually should be considered a crime changing core files. See [Why don't we hack core?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/59054/15055).

Comment: @MattFletcher, you can use [hook_node_links_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_links_alter/8.6.x), which provides the node (to get the content type) and the view mode as context. This hook only works in a module.