# Limit Change to Read More Link in Node Teaser to One Content Type

Tags: theming, 8

Building on [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194973/rename-read-more):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_links().
 */
function bartik_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
    if (isset($variables['links']['node-readmore'])) {
      $variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#title'] = t('Read more custom text');
    }
}
```

does anyone know how to build the if statement to further limit the change in the read more link to a particular content type? I'm working in Drupal 8, not 7.

Answer (score 2):

Add following to your THEMENAME.theme file

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node.html.twig.
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    // ...
    if ($variables['teaser']) {
    $node_type = &drupal_static('node_type');
    $node_type = $variables['node']->getType();
  }
}


/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_links().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
  $node_type = &drupal_static('node_type');
    if (isset($variables['links']['node-readmore'])) {
        // Change link title according to machine name of node_type
        if ($node_type == 'article') {
            $variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#title'] = t('Custom Text');
        }
    } 
}
```

Clear Cache.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by getting the bundle from the URL object that's part of the link:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['links']) && (isset($variables['links']['node-readmore'])) && (isset($variables['links']['node-readmore']['link'])) && (isset($variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#url']))) {
    if ($entity = $variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#url']->getOption('entity')) {
      if (($bundle = $entity->bundle()) && ($bundle == 'article')) $variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#title'] = t('Read the article');
    }
  }
}
```